# Why is the this code's output 242 and not 243

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var x = 2;

function fun() {
  x = 3;
  var x = 4;
  document.write(x);
}

document.write(x);

fun()

document.write(x);
```

Can someone help me understand the flow of control. Why is the output 242 when it looks like output should be 243. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `var` declaration in the function is interpreted as if it appeared at the very start of the function block. All references to `x` in the function are references to the local variable, not the global `x`.

Comment: Are you sure of the answer? Sorry to ask.

Comment: it's simple, just printed the output as per the scope of variable.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. You're seeing that it prints 242 right?

Comment: thanks for the answer. it helped a lot ^_^

Comment: Hoisting is confusing. I would have expected 444.

Comment: @Lewis Then you need to read about [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).

Comment: @Lewis It can't be **444**. The global variable is never changed. And its printed two times. So there will be two `2`s

Comment: @Maheer @Pointy - Thanks. I thought using `var` before x = 4 would have replaced `x = 2` when hoisted. I clearly misunderstand what `var` does.

Comment: According to [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) hoisting happens only in case of a declaration. In the question, it's initialised too. So is it hoisting that's happening?

Comment: Yes, the declaration of `x` is hoisted in the function, and the global `x` is shadowed inside the function because of the hoisted declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you modify the `x=3` it is not actually changing the global variable `x` but the variable declared in the function block (as `var` variables have function scope). As the declaration `var x` is hoisted to the top and then the modification to `x = 3` happens

```html
<script>
      var x=2;
      function fun(){
          //var x; hoisted to the top;
          console.log("x is hoisted here and uninitialized value will be", x)
   x=3; //initialized, actually referring to the variable declared in the function scope 
   var x = 4; //declared but hoisted at the top
   document.write(x);
 }
 document.write(x);
 fun()
 document.write(x);
</script>
```

To really change the variable at the global scope, use `window.x` to refer to it:

```html
<script>
     var x=2;
     function fun(){
      window.x=3; //modifying the global variable 'x`
      var x = 4; 
      document.write(x);
     }
     document.write(x);
     fun()
     document.write(x);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Your explanation provided a lot of clarity!

Answer (score 6):

This due to hoisting. The variable `x` which is local inside `fun` is brought to top of scope and then assigned the value `3`  and after that assign value `4`. So **line `x=3;` is not changing global variable but its changing local variable**. The code acts like

```
function fun(){
    var x;
    x=3;
    x=4;
    document.write(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man.Really helped. :)

Comment: @SushantPradhan Accept the answer with which you are most satisfied.